# Android. How to clone Editable

Tags: java, android

Does exist some simple method to clone Editable (EditText.getText())?
There is no constructor of copy so I can't simply write:

Editable documetTextCopy = new Editable(documentText.getText());
and it seems Editable doesn't implement Cloneable.

Comment: Why do you need to clone it? Would it better just to convert to String by calling `EditText.getText().toString()`? You would have more flexibility that way.

Comment: Converting to string leads to loosing of spans. And I need to save them in my copy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
Editable old = documentText.getText();
Editable copy = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(old);
```

Comment: It is helpful. Thanks!